# Replace commas with new lines for string in column of Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have some DataFrame:

```
d = {'fruit': ['apple', 'pear', 'peach'], 'values': ['apple_1_0,peach_1_5','pear_1_3','mango_1_0,banana_1_0,pineapple_1_10']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

fruit   values
0   apple   apple_1_0,peach_1_5
1   pear    pear_1_3
2   peach   mango_1_0,banana_1_0,pineapple_1_10
```

I'd like to separate the strings in the `values` column by new lines instead of by commas, e.g.:

```
    fruit   values
    0   apple   apple_1_0
                peach_1_5
    1   pear    pear_1_3
    2   peach   mango_1_0
                banana_1_0
                pineapple_1_10
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the values into list using `.str.split` and `explode()`

```
df=df.assign(values =df['values'].str.split(',')).explode('values')
```

as noted by @cs95
If you wanted index without repeated values. Please try

```
df.set_index('fruit', append=True)['values'].str.split(',').explode().to_frame()
```

Comment: Closer to their output, something like `df.set_index('fruit', append=True)['values'].str.split(',').explode().to_frame()` would do.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying pd.explode() as well. The problem here is I'd like the output frame to still contain only 3 rows.

Comment: What do you mean three rows?

Comment: as in the above example, 3 rows - apple, pear, peach

Comment: Please try `df=df.assign(values =df['values'].str.split(',')).explode('values').set_index('fruit').sort_index().reset_index()
df['fruit']=df['fruit'].mask(df['fruit'].duplicated(),"")
`

Comment: I think what I'm trying to do might not be possible. Still 3 rows, but I want the `values` column, when it contains any commas, to split to new lines, without creating new rows. Just as in the example in my post. Rows 0 and 2 would have multiple rows within their `values` column.